# ¿Es correcto este uso de "jactar"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, verbos, solicitud-de-término

He visto en un [periódico digital](https://altavozdesucesos.es/video-ivan-espinosa-se-jacta-de-maria-jesus-montero-con-una-tableta-cinase-a-la-pregunta-gracias/):

> Vídeo. Iván Espinosa **se jacta** de María Jesús Montero con una tableta: «Cíñase a la pregunta. Gracias»
>
> Iván Espinosa **se jactó** de la ministra de Hacienda
>
> Iván Espinosa, portavoz de VOX en el Congreso de los Diputados, **se jactó** este miércoles de la ministra de Hacienda, María Jesús Montero, cuando este, en mitad de una respuesta de la dirigente socialista, sacó una tableta con el siguiente mensaje: «Por favor, cíñase a la pregunta. Gracias».

Ese uso no me parece que sea correcto, dado que el [Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas](https://www.rae.es/dpd/jactar), indica:

> jactarse. ‘Alabarse o presumir de algo’.

y el [Diccionario de la Lengua](https://dle.rae.es/jactar) define *jactar* como:

> 1. tr. desus. Mover, agitar.
> 2. prnl. Dicho de una persona: Alabarse excesiva y presuntuosamente, con fundamento o sin él y aun de acciones criminales o vergonzosas.

¿Es correcto el uso citado? Si no lo es, ¿cuál sería una alternativa mejor a "jactarse"?

Answer (score 7):

> ¿Es correcto el uso citado?

No. 
La expresión no es en absoluto correcta, ya que, tal cual se consigna, la jactancia refiere a una auto-alabanza, nunca a una crítica o a un rechazo a un tercero.

No hace falta conocer a los participantes ni el trasfondo de sus rivalidades políticas para comprender que la expresión falla en reflejar la actitud de amonestación del diputado a la respuesta de la ministra (exhibiéndole una preparada crítica)

> ¿Cuál sería una alternativa mejor a jactarse?

Alguna que acertadamente de cuenta de su ánimo de "[disentir](https://dle.rae.es/disentir)" —*no ajustarse al sentir o parecer de alguien*—, "criticar", "rechazar", "reprobar", "descalificar", "desdeñar", o hasta "mofarse de"  las palabras —oídas con desdén, en una puesta en escena reprochante (para lo cual empleó una pantalla digital)

Un título más ajustado a la situación podría haber sido :

> **Vídeo**. Iván Espinosa *critica* [o *rechaza*] a María Jesús Montero por medio de una tableta «Cíñase a la pregunta. Gracias»

O, acaso, (dado el parecido sonoro), la expresión buscada fuera:

> **Vídeo**. Iván Espinosa "***se mofa***" de María Jesús Montero con una tableta «Cíñase a la pregunta. Gracias»